# Sorting a list of strings with another list of strings

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort an Event class by nearest geographical location. I have a list of event objects with the state the event takes place in `event.state = 'Wyoming'`. I also have a list of nearby states `nearby = ['Wyoming', 'Colorado', 'Nebraska', 'South Dakota', 'etc']`

I would like to implement a custom sort method

```
def sort_by_nearby_location():
  # Take event.state and compare to nearby states list and return sorted list
```

Is there a method in python that would allow me sort my list of events by their state according to the order I have set in my `nearby` list? What would be the best way to tackle this type of probelem?

Comment: You can do something like `states.sort(key=lambda k: nearby.index(k))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted()` takes a `key` argument. This argument can be a lambda or a function that transforms your original list element, for instance to the index of that element in your `nearby` list.

```
sorted(events, key=lambda event: nearby.index(event.state))
```